# No providerName Found When Using Configuration Builder

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, web-config, asp-net-config-builders

### web.config

```
<connectionStrings configBuilders="CS_Environment">
   <add name="connectionA" connectionString="EnvVarA" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   <add name="connectionB" connectionString="EnvVarB" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The `ConnectionStringSettings` object's `ProviderName` will be an empty string instead of `"System.Data.SqlClient"` or `"System.Data.EntityClient"`.

The `Name` and `ConnectionString` properties map just fine. If I remove the `configBuilders` attribute from the  tag, the provider name will be populated. Of course, the correct environment variable no longer will be fetched but the point is the configBuilder is breaking this.

Here is the configuration builder being used for the connection strings:

```
<add name="CS_Environment" mode="Greedy" prefix="ConnStr_" stripPrefix="true"
           type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder,
           Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently accepted answer of setting providerName order does not seem to have any effect, at least not in v2.0.

**In v2.0, the issue is caused by a bug in `ConnectionStringsSectionHandler` which under `Greedy` mode completely replaces entire configuration element.**

#### Why is this happening?

This is related to how `Greedy` works: it fetches settings from your backing store first and adds every found entry to configuration. Due to the bug, for `connectionStrings` it
actually does drop-then-add-new, losing all extra attributes (including `providerName`) in the process.

#### Workaround: use `Strict` mode

When using `Strict` mode the configuration values are looked up first and every entry found is updated with override value (if present). Meaning the original conncetionString xml node is kept with all it's attributes, including `prividerName`.

#### Fix: implement custom handler

Start by inheriting from default `ConnectionStringsSectionHandler` and then fix the issue to reuse existing connectionString (or just apply a providerName suitable to your needs).

Important step is to [register your app to use your handler over the default one](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders#section-handlers).

Comment: I do not understand why, but I had to change mode to Strict from Greedy and put providerName attribute before connectionString in the <add> tag of the web.config file. Thank you for this solution.